# Delphi - how to move a control and refresh it

Tags: delphi

For a programming exercise in Delphi I want to scroll an image across the screen 1 pixel at a time and repaint it each time I move it, so it looks like it is actually moving. At the moment Delphi just draws it at the start and end, so it isn't smooth. I tried Repaint and also Refresh, but neither worked. I also tried making it visible and invisible to see if that would work, but no luck.

```
image1.Visible := true;
for i := 0 to 50 do
begin
   image1.Visible := false;
   image1.Left := image1.Left + 1;
   image1.Repaint(); // this doesn't work...
   for j := 0 to 1000000 do
   begin
      k := i + j; // do nothing code
   end; 
   image1.Visible := true;
end;
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: Speaking about uglyness: busy-loop is not missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 50 do
  begin
    image1.Left := image1.Left + 1;
    Application.ProcessMessages;
    sleep(100);
  end;
end;
```

You could also do `Image1.Update` instead of `Application.ProcessMessages` but then the application would stop responding to Windows messages; hence, it would "freeze". Anyhow, this is a very ugly way to do an animation (very ugly!), but if it is just an exercise, then ...

Comment: Thanks. This works. I know it will flicker and look ugly, but that's Windows.

Comment: @Thomas O: No, that is not Windows. It is just bad programming... (Sorry...) If you really want to do animations, you should do all drawing manually (using GDI), and not just move a visual VCL control! Also, you should employ double-buffering. If you need more advanced rendering, you can use OpenGL. I have done a lot of 3D graphics and animations in Delphi. See www.algosim.se for a few examples. Also, the triggering event in an animation should be part of a timer message, not a for loop. This will somehow freeze the app. (Try closing the window while the image is moving.)

Comment: @Thomas O: No, that's not "that's Windows". That's you doing things incorrectly. Just so you know, it's possible to do this properly, so that the image does not flicker. GDI graphics, while not as fast as anything hardware-accelerated, is still a viable way to draw stuff.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand - I mostly develop PyGTK on Linux/Ubuntu and the repainting of any object is automatic and restricted to the changed bounding box, so this wouldn't flicker on GTK.

Comment: @Andreas @Thomas O  I was about to write exactly the same. Windows is not ugly.

Comment: @Thomas O I'm sure PyGTK is very good, but even this code with ProcessMessages and Sleep will not flicker on Windows either

Comment: @Thomas O: This is wrong because of many reasons, not only flicker. It's not a good idea to ProcessMessages like that, for example. What if you receive another OnClick from inside of this Onclick, the same one or one for a different animation? What if you get WM_QUIT and your application terminates while in OnClick? Or the active form is closed and destroyed?

Comment: @David Heffernan well it does flicker with Application.ProcessMessages and Sleep. Maybe it's because it is an older computer with little/no hardware acceleration.

Comment: @Thomas O: I *think* that this might flicker in Windows XP, but not in Windows 7 because Windows 7 draws windows in a different way, so Windows 7 is more tolerant against bad programming practices. Still, this is by far not a good way to do animations in Windows 7 either. For one thing, what happens if you click the "X" button when the image is moving? Use a timer instead, and do the drawing using GDI instead of moving a visual control.

Comment: @Thomas O No flicker for me. I'm on Windows 7. What version of Windows are you on? Or are you perhaps running through WINE?!!

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand Running Windows XP, and yep, the close button doesn't work, but it was only a quick demo and I'm *not* going to use visual controls for animations.

Comment: @David Heffernan using Windows XP on an old Dell with 2D hardware acceleration at best.

Comment: @Thomas O There you go. It's not fair to compare modern Linux with XP - XP is 10 years old!

Comment: @David Heffernan, I suppose you're right here, although XP SP3 isn't that old... not sure if they updated the drawing code, though.

Comment: @Thomas O SP3 is just that, a service pack. They fix bugs and close security holes. They don't re-architect the OS. Vista introduced a whole new rendering engine which is a huge improvement.

Comment: I think it's important to point out that a for loop incrementing a variable to simulate a delay is never a good idea either.  The delay will likely be different on every PC.  Reminds me of when I had an old Tetris like game on a 486 at 33MHz and then ran it on a Pentium when I found it again a few years later and it was unplayable because it ran about 10 times faster :-)

Answer (score 5):

A much better way to do this is to use a timer. In Delphi that means an object of class TTimer. Each time the timer fires you just increment the Left property. You probably want a counter that disables the timer once it has fired as many times as you desire.

Comment: +1 I just added this to my comment above. And, most importantly, you shouldn't do animations by moving visual controls!